# Analytic functions with nonessential singularity at infinity must be a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise from Alhfors Complex Analysis book- to show that an analytic function with a nonessential singularity at infinity must be a polynomial.
It seems like it should probably be pretty straight forward, but I must be missing something.
If it has a removable singularity at infinity then it extends to an analytic function on the Riemann sphere, and so must be constant by Liouville's theorem.
What if there is a pole at infinity though?
This was homework some time ago, and  I never finished it :/ but have been thinking about it again recently.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another hint: look at the function $f(\frac{1}{z})$ at z = 0, it has a nonessential singularity at 0...

Comment: I think I have it now. Funny thing is I tried looking at f(1/z) before and for some reason missed it. I think I have it now. Thank you :)

Comment: How do I write the proof formally? suppose f is not a polynomial. So positive power of $z$ is non-termnating. consider $f(1/z)$ The negative power is non-terminating. So has an essential singularity at $z=0$. So, $f$ has essential singularity at $f$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: consider the Laurent series in the annulus $0 < |z| < \infty$.

Comment: Ahlfors book hasn't introduced Laurent series yet, so I was looking for a way along another path- hopefully. Thank you though.