# Non constant entire function satisfying two conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non constant entire function satisfying the following two conditions:

a) $f(0)=0$

b) For every positive real number $M$, the set $\{z:|f(z)|<M\}$ is connected.

Prove that $f(z)=cz^n$ for some constant $c$ and positive integer $n$.

Since zeroes of an analytic function are isolated, I can take a closed disc of positive radius in which $0$ is the only zero of $f$. The conclusion I need, suggests that I must prove that $f$ has a pole at infinity. That will prove that $f$ is a polynomial. In addition I must prove that $0$ is the only zero for $f$. Is there any more elegant way of approaching the solution? Help me to prove the two assertions I made above.

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680346/entire-function-such-that-f0-0/1681115#1681115